# Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>' in asp.net mvc2 after publishing the website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I am using asp.net mvc2 and the project is running very well from visual studio, but when I published the project shows this error.
Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'

thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks Darin I found the solution. I have to add this

```
<pages
         pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
         pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
         userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

in my web.config

Comment: Wow I had the same problem when deploying a ASP.NET MVC 2 (and .NET 4) on a Windows 2003 server with the .NET 4 runtime. What is strange is I had been successful on 3 other servers, but my PROD server would fail to start the app until I added the statement above. So big thanks!

Comment: I experienced the same issue with MVC 3 with .NET 4, despite the application pool being configured for v4. I have three instances of the site all with identical app pools and only one runs without these parameters. Note that I also changed the "Version=" to 3.0.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0 to reflect my version of MVC.

Comment: Small comment - this web.cofig is locates in View folder.

Comment: This applies to MVC 5 as well.  System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage loaded fine, but System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<T> didn't work.  After specifying the viewTypeParseFilter type in web.config, the views with model type T started working.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that the application pool in the web server is configured to use the CLR 4.0:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while debugging my asp.net mvc 2 project with VS 2010 Ultimate and I finally had to add the 3 parameters `pageParserFilterType`, `pageBaseType` & `userControlBaseType` to the page attributre in the **web.config** to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

Mazen's answer also can solve the similar exception for the environment: MVC3, Framework4 and ASP.NET WebForms & MVC together in one project. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had deployed an MVC3 app to our QA environment with a new Area, and got a similar error. 
We use WIX, and in my case I had forgotten to add the web.config file in the area/.../View folder.

Added the "web.config" to the Wix project and all worked fine.